# How to randomly separate data in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

suppose we have an array storing data,

```
data=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
      10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1];
```

Then I want to randomly split the data into two array, one contains 3 columns of the data and the other 7, what I think of is to use randperm function,

```
index = randperm(10,3);
```

then

```
data1 = data(:,index);
```

my question is how to represent the other data set which contains the other remaining 7 column of the original data set? Thanks.

Comment: Could you instead shuffle the array and then subset the first 3 and last 7?

Comment: Also, you can use `ind1 = randsample(10,3)` to randomly generate three column indices, and then `ind2 = setdiff(1:10,ind1)` are the other column indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
index = randperm(10);
data1 = data(:,index(1:3));
data2 = data(:,index(4:10));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution that may feel more intuitive depending on the situation.

```
index = randperm(10,3);
data1 = data(:,index);
data(:,index) = [];
```

Note that this is especially appealing when you try to draw a few values from a huge (sparse) matrix.